# PHP trigger_error function throws error before the page complete. Can it possible to delay it. or make to run inside a function?

Tags: php

I am trying to display warning and notifications using PHP `trigger_error()`. But it displays the result above the header. i mean it prints after the body tag. Is it possible to execute it after the page completely loaded or make it render inside a particular div.

I can't show my error screenshot, so here is an link to get my [error image](http://projects.kvcodes.com/trigger_error.png).

```
if (isset($_GET['AddedID'])) {
$order_no = $_GET['AddedID'];
trigger_error(sprintf( _("Order # %d has been entered."),$order_no), E_USER_NOTICE);  }
```

here the diaplay_notification will call the

Comment: Can you show us the part of the code where you have this problem ?

Comment: yea sure, here is my code

Comment: What is the html context ?

Comment: sorry i couldn't get you. you mean html code or php function for all those code. Actually i showed the screenshot image on the link. Which will help you to see the html code. and the php function i wrote it above.

Comment: Your image shows the output `html`, what is the source (`html + php)`? On your image, the sentence is "has been updated" while your error is "has been entered", is it the same output or another case ? What I want to see is the location of the php code relative to the `<body>` tag?

Comment: i am using a common function to write html codes upto body tag,  than my custom function running there  to create a main container div.  thereafter i  added the function. but it echo the result before the header and container  prints through php function.

Comment: I would suggest  to catch it somewhere in code (try - catch  block), to prevent it from propagation to default handler - top of page before header

Comment: Investigate function [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). It allows you to install an error handler (i.e. some code) that is called when an error/warning/notice is triggered by PHP or by your code. Your error handler could accumulate the error messages in a buffer on each call (instead of displaying them). Display the content of the buffer at the end of the script (or when you think it's the most appropriate).

Comment: Regarding your sample code, `trigger_error()` is not meant to be used for input validation. It is a debugging helper for the developer; input validation is part of your application, it's not debugging.

Answer (score 1):

try this, put the trigger_error() inside a div, tell me if it works out for you.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="border:solid red 1px; width:500px">SOME TEXT HERE</div>
    <?php
        echo '<div style="border:solid red 1px; width:500px">';
        trigger_error("A NICE ERROR MESSAGE");
        echo '</div>';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code. it works if i am not using fancybox. but if i load the contents through fancybox iframe it renders first.

Comment: ok, when you said fancybox you meant a popup window that shows an image/form etc in the center of the screen and the rest of the screen is blurred out, is that it? could you post the html + php code here so we can see how to get the required output?